# If the curve has two tangents passing through the coordinate origin, find the value range of parameter a

Tags: functions

If the curve `y == (x + a) E^x` has two tangents passing through the coordinate origin, find the value range of parameter a

```
y[x_] := (x + a) E^x
dt = D[y[x], x] // FullSimplify
Reduce[Discriminant[FactorList[y[x] - dt x][[-1, 1]], x] > 0, a]
```

This code can find the range of a. But I don't understand the code in the last paragraph.

```
Reduce[Discriminant[FactorList[y[x] - dt x][[-1, 1]], x] > 0, a]
```

What do you mean? Can you explain it separately? Why can we find the range of a in this way? What else is there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For any fixed point `{x,y}` on `y[x_] = (x + a) E^x`,the tangen line is

```
Y - y[x] - D[y[x], x] (X - x) == 0
```

here `{X,Y}` is the point on the tangent line.

When the tangent line through `{0,0}`, then

```
Y - y[x] - D[y[x], x] (X - x) == 0 /. {X -> 0, Y -> 0} // Simplify
```

> `E^x (a (-1 + x) + x^2) == 0`

It means that

```
a (-1 + x) + x^2==0
```

If there two distinct tangent line through `{0,0}`, the above equation has  two distinct solutions, that is

```
Discriminant[a (-1 + x) + x^2, x] > 0
```

```
Reduce[Discriminant[a (-1 + x) + x^2, x] > 0, a]
```

> `a < -4 || a > 0`.

Comment: ```FactorList[y[x] - dt x]```Why is this result:```{{-1, 1}, {E^x, 1}, {-a + a x + x^2, 1}}```？

Comment: @csn899  `FactorList[y[x] - dt x]` just the equation `E^x (a (-1 + x) + x^2) == 0` .  There are two factors of `E^x (a (-1 + x) + x^2) `, `E^x ` and `a (-1 + x) + x^2`

Comment: ```-E^x (a (-1 + x) + x^2)```,thank you! I already understand!